# Sort PHP array by numeric portion of an element

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

PLEASE stop deleting my questions and associating them with previous questions. Those other answers do not solve this specific question.

I have this array:

```
$elements = ('10 miles', '2 miles', '> 50 miles', '1 mile', '> 500 miles');
```

How do I sort this by just the numeric portion so I get this:

```
$elements = ('1 mile', '2 miles', '> 10 miles', '> 50 miles', '> 500 miles');
```

I have tried this:

```
$newElements = [];

for each ($elements as $item) {
    $item = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $item);
    $item = intval($item);  // just in case
    $newElements[] = $item;
}

usort($newElements, 'comp');

function comp($item1, $item2) {
    return $item1 > $item2;
}
```

But I still get this:

```
10
25
40
4
60
```

Comment: Use `usort()`. The comparison function can use a regular expression to extract the numeric part, then compare them.

Comment: The duplicate the moderator flagged your question as does answer your question though. Specifically [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) to compare the values, you just need to adapt the answer for your use-case. Reposting a question that was closed may result in disciplinary actions.

Comment: @Barmar - I did? I posted what I have tried, from the other thread.

Comment: @Ping That wasn't in the question when I posted my comment.

Comment: [`natsort()`](https://3v4l.org/D9vbe)

Answer (score 1):

You're sorting the array of numbers that you extracted, rather than sorting the original array. You need to extract the number in the comparison function.

```
function comp($str1, $str2) {
    $num1 = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $str1));
    $num2 = intval(preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $str2));
    return $num1 - $num2;
}

usort($elements, 'comp');
```

The comparison function should return a number, not a boolean. The sign of the number indicates which of the inputs is higher.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [usort](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.usort.php) with [filter_var](https://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-var) function.
It works good for you array:

```
$elements = array('10 miles', '2 miles', '> 50 miles', '1 mile', '> 500 miles');

usort($elements, function($a, $b) {
    return filter_var($a, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT) > filter_var($b, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
});


var_dump($elements);
```

And output should be:

```
array(5) {
  [0]=>
  string(6) "1 mile"
  [1]=>
  string(7) "2 miles"
  [2]=>
  string(8) "10 miles"
  [3]=>
  string(10) "> 50 miles"
  [4]=>
  string(11) "> 500 miles"
}
```

Comment: Please note that `usort()` expects an integer return value in PHP 8+ to avoid the "Deprecated: usort(): Returning bool from comparison function is deprecated, return an integer less than, equal to, or greater than zero" error.